# Finding subgroup of Z15 generated by subset {4,6}

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the best way to approach this problem? The way I am attempting to do is seperating subgroups.

For example, $\langle 4 \rangle = \{4,8,12,1,5,9,13,2,6,10,14,3,7,11,0\}$

then taking that information and proceeding to find:

$1(4) \equiv  4 \pmod{15}$

And the same for $\langle 4 \rangle$. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Yes, that is an idea, yet if you already found out that $\;\langle 4\rangle=\Bbb Z_{15}\;$ , then we clearly have $\;\langle 4,6\rangle=\Bbb Z_{15}\;$ , no need to check also for $\;6\;$ ...

Comment: Interesting, I do see theres some common elements such as 6mod(15) and 12mod(15). So would I only need to take the elements of <4> and thats it?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Note that the more generators you add, the smaller the generated group becomes.